# Getting around an Undefined

Tags: undefined

So, I am making a card game, and I am trying to write the code for a common interation. The issue is that when the array containing the card is empty, it is technically undefined, which is not an issue.

However, I need it to be in the code so that when there is an element in there, it will know to grab the proper data from the array. Presently, if there is no card in the array, the entire code stops.

Is there a way to get the code to skip over the element if it is undefined. Here is a bit of my code so that you can better understand what I am talking about.

```
    function Takedmg(){
    if (MageTurn == "false"){
        arm = Mwepons[2]["effect"];  /* **this is the line that is sometimes undefined** */
        var tmpdmg = (TdmgW * Onedmg) - (arm * Onedmg);
        MageHealth.style.clip = "rect("+ parseInt(basehlth + tmpdmg) +"px, 200px, 200px, 0px)";
        basehlth = basehlth + tmpdmg;
        console.log("dmg:" + tmpdmg);
        rage.style.height = crntRage + (5 * Onerage) + "px";
        crntRage = crntRage + (5 * Onerage);
        Mwepons[2]["duration"] = Mwepons[2]["duration"] - 1;
        Wwepons[0]["duration"] = Wwepons[0]["duration"] - 1;
        if(Wwepons[1]["cardName"] !== "Shield"){Wwepons[1]["duration"] = Wwepons[1]["duration"] - 1;}
        if(Mwepons[2]["duration"] < 1){
            Mwepons[2] = undefined;
            armourDM.style.backgroundImage = "none";
        }
        if(Wwepons[0]["duration"] < 1){
            Wwepons[0] = undefined;
            wepon1DM.style.backgroundImage = "none";
        }
        if(Wwepons[1]["duration"] < 1){
            Wwepons[1] = undefined;
            wepon2DM.style.backgroundImage = "none";
        }
        console.log(tmpdmg)
    }
    else if (MageTurn == "true"){
        var tmpdmgM = TdmgM * OnedmgM;
        WarriorHealth.style.clip = "rect("+ parseInt(basehlth2 + tmpdmgM) + "px, 900px, 700px, 0px)";
        basehlth2 = basehlth2 + tmpdmgM;
        console.log("damg"+ tmpdmgM)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some psuedo code:

```
(Some loop)
  if(element == undefined) continue;
Do logic here
```

Or

```
 (Some block) 
   if(element == undefined) return
 Logic here
```